# r leaflet layers control (addLayersControl) does not hide legends belonging to a group

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

In the tiny example shown below, I have two features associated with each country (polygons) in the map, namely: randomA, randomB. Each feature has its own legend, so I armed a group named "randomA" containing the polygons coloured with feature randomA and its corresponding legend. I did the same for group "randomB". When the map is depicted, leaflet correctly shows or hides polygons for features "randomA" and "randomB". However legends are always shown stacked  on the bottom right corner. 
This is the code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

# From http://data.okfn.org/data/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m
countries <- readOGR("json/countries.geojson")
n <- nrow(countries)

# Add two random fields
set.seed(15)
countries@data$randomA <- rnorm(n, 1000, 250)
countries@data$randomB <- rnorm(n, 10000, 3000)

map <- leaflet(countries) %>% addTiles()

pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "YlGnBu",
  domain = countries$randomA
)

map <- map %>%
  addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1,
              color = ~pal(randomA), group = "randomA"
  ) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = ~randomA,
            title = "random A",
            labFormat = labelFormat(prefix = "$"),
            opacity = 1, group = "randomA"
  )

qpal <- colorQuantile("RdYlBu", countries$gdp_md_est, n = 5)
map <- map %>%
  addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1,
              color = ~qpal(randomB), group = "randomB"
  ) %>%
  addLegend(
    "bottomright",
    pal = qpal, 
    values = ~randomB, 
    opacity = 1, group = "randomB"
  )

# Finally control layers:
map <- map %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("randomA", "randomB"),
    position = "bottomleft",
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = F)
  )

map
```

A snapshot of the result is shown in the image below:

[image: output of the code]

Also, in the actual problem I have to represent nine of these groups, so I wish I had all the legends in the same place.
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try using overlay groups instead of base groups:

```
addLayersControl(
overlayGroups = c("randomA", "randomB"),
position = "bottomleft",
options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = F)
```

)

Comment: This, however, does not solve the problem of having the legends stacked on the bottom right corner.

Comment: does it allow you to select them on and off?

Comment: Yes, it allows me to select them on and off, but they stay in their place.

Comment: that is not useful...for both leaflet and rbokeh I have had to post modify some of the javascript or JSON to get things to do what I want as seamlessly as if they were created in their native environments...this may be one of those times. Try searching for the JS implementation and see what solutions are available and then open the JS file?